# How to change ip or proxy in python code without http request

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, proxy

I tried to find away to put proxy in code that use internet
All changing proxy i found they do it for only browsers or do http requests
But if i want to send email with `smtblib` with different ip how can i do that

Can’t find any documentation for something like that

Comment: "only for browsers or HTTP requests". smtp still uses TCP

Comment: I can change the ip through tcp ?

Comment: Yes, but there isnt insane amounts of support becasue it doesnt make sense to send a email with a proxy unless it was for some sort of malicious intent

Comment: no bro for pentration testing